# NAs in a data frame split by country in R

Tags: r, mean, imputation

I would like to impute NA's in a dataframe with means of observed data in each country. In other words, while dealing with NAs, the values in the specific country should be taken into consideration. For instance;

```
Date                Country        Battles       Riots
March 2018          Afghanistan    380            NA
March 2018          Yemen          88             5
March 2018          Mali           45             NA
April 2018          Afghanistan    350            NA
April 2018          Yemen          NA             66
April 2018          Mali           67             NA
May 2018            Afghanistan    NA             7
May 2018            Yemen          NA             NA
May 2018            Mali           NA             6
```

I have used the following code, but obviously it calculates the means without taking the country specific information.

```
for(i in 6:ncol(my_data)) {
 my_data[ , i][is.na(my_data[ , i])] <- mean(my_data[ , i], na.rm = TRUE)
 }
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Country) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(Battles, Riots), ~ replace_na(.x, mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

which returns

```r
  Date       Country     Battles Riots
  <chr>      <chr>         <dbl> <dbl>
1 March 2018 Afghanistan     380   7  
2 March 2018 Yemen            88   5  
3 March 2018 Mali             45   6  
4 April 2018 Afghanistan     350   7  
5 April 2018 Yemen            88  66  
6 April 2018 Mali             67   6  
7 May 2018   Afghanistan     365   7  
8 May 2018   Yemen            88  35.5
9 May 2018   Mali             56   6
```

### Data

```r
structure(list(Date = c("March 2018", "March 2018", "March 2018", 
"April 2018", "April 2018", "April 2018", "May 2018", "May 2018", 
"May 2018"), Country = c("Afghanistan", "Yemen", "Mali", "Afghanistan", 
"Yemen", "Mali", "Afghanistan", "Yemen", "Mali"), Battles = c(380, 
88, 45, 350, NA, 67, NA, NA, NA), Riots = c(NA, 5, NA, NA, 66, 
NA, 7, NA, 6)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` option (borrow `df` from [@Martin Gal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68704641/12158757))

```
setDT(df)[
  ,
  c("Battles", "Riots") := lapply(
    .(Battles, Riots),
    function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))
  ), 
  Country
][]
```

gives

```
         Date     Country Battles Riots
1: March 2018 Afghanistan     380   7.0
2: March 2018       Yemen      88   5.0
3: March 2018        Mali      45   6.0
4: April 2018 Afghanistan     350   7.0
5: April 2018       Yemen      88  66.0
6: April 2018        Mali      67   6.0
7:   May 2018 Afghanistan     365   7.0
8:   May 2018       Yemen      88  35.5
9:   May 2018        Mali      56   6.0
```